# What is the best tool for file-shredding on a memory card?

Tags: memory-card, file-shredding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a program to truly delete all deleted files?](https://superuser.com/questions/33886/is-there-a-program-to-truly-delete-all-deleted-files)

Hi, I want to shred the contents of my memory card and I don't want to be able to recover any files from that memory card...Is it possible??  If so then which tool is best?

Comment: Are we talking about physical shred (hammer, paper shredder, acid, etc), or actual file shredding that you asked about 30 minutes ago and which got closed as duplicate?

Comment: @gnoupi file shredding

Comment: Ok, actually, the other question (http://superuser.com/questions/4678/erasing-data-before-selling-a-computer) doesn't really contain a solution to apply for a single memory card, only to wipe an entire computer. There is probably another question about securely erasing individual files, trying to find it.

Comment: Ok, found it: http://superuser.com/questions/33886/is-there-a-program-to-truly-delete-all-deleted-files

Answer (score 0):

[A Blentec blender](http://www.blendtec.com/willitblend/videos.aspx?type=unsafe&video=iphone3g) will do the job. (I couldn't help myself from answering with that)

Seriously,though, on linux, a `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sdx` where sdx is your flash card will work fine. On windows, I'm pretty sure that [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) carries the option of multiple erasure of a custom folder. you can also use [SDelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx) or [Secure Erase Util](http://cmrr.ucsd.edu/people/Hughes/SecureErase.shtml) or even [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/)

Comment: When a duplicate is shown in comments, please refrain from answering the question, as it will most likely be closed. Consider adding your answer on the "original" question, if it wasn't given already, to keep answers in one place.

Comment: Nobody had commented when I started to answer. But you're absolutely right Gnoupi. I should have flagged for mod.

Comment: no problem, though. It was only a suggestion for next time. SDelete and Secure Erase Util haven't been suggested yet on the other question, I see, you could port a part of your answer on it.

Comment: Because [SD cards can use wear leveling internally](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27619/is-it-true-that-a-sd-mmc-card-does-wear-levelling-with-its-own-controller) overwriting a single file does not erase the original. Even overwriting the whole card may not work because of reserve cells. Instead the [SD card formatter should be used](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/). The [manual](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/SDFormatter_4e.pdf) (in Jenglish) explains the procedure, see "5.1.2 Format Option Window". There is no Linux version, only Windows and Mac.