# What are the techniques for securely erasing data in Linux?

Tags: linux, software-rec, file-management, secure-erase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to wipe free disk space in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/19326/how-to-wipe-free-disk-space-in-linux)

This question is inspired by [What is the best tool for file-shredding on a memory card?](https://superuser.com/questions/125333/what-is-the-best-tool-for-file-shredding-on-a-memory-card-closed), in which [brice](https://superuser.com/users/25890/brice) recommended the simple pattern for wiping an SD card using `dd if=/dev/random`. That's the solution to the problem I googled. brice++

I saw that question refer to the more general one: [Is there a program to truly delete all deleted files?](https://superuser.com/questions/33886/is-there-a-program-to-truly-delete-all-deleted-files). But that question is tagged `windows`. I'd like to add the Linux answer to our knowledge base. I use `shred -uz` FWIW.

I'd also like to hear from experts about success against forensic techniques. (No, I am not under threat of indictment. I have nothing to hide from authorities. I'm just curious. ;) Does `shred(1)` have a track record for thwarting subpoenas? What about brice's technique for the SD card? There are no forensic techniques to recover from flash once it's been overwritten in just a single pass, right?

Last, kudos to [splattne](https://superuser.com/users/187/splattne) for linking to [Guidelines for Media Sanitization](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-88/NISTSP800-88%5Frev1.pdf) (PDF) in [another related Windows question](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/securely-erasing-all-data-from-a-hard-drive). But that document doesn't mention Linux or UNIX in 43 pages!

Comment: I know of a program called `BleachBit` - I use it to flush my browser cache whenever I log in (they get really big, really fast), and it has an option to wipe free space.

Comment: I doubt running shred or any utility would prevent you from getting a subpoenas.  If you are really worried, why not default to secure and store things encrypted.

Comment: @Zoredache I wouldn't expect a utility to prevent one from getting a subpoena. By "thwart" I mean can anyone point me to a report of someone being served a subpoena, but the data was not recoverable. That's good evidence of security.

Comment: Even encryption may not be enough to protect against legal measures - it's not legal in all countries and even where it is there may be ways to compel you to give up the decrypted data (see e.g. this [article](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/361693/teenager-jailed-for-refusing-to-reveal-encryption-keys) about the UK).  Perhaps the only way to be truly safe is using encryption with data-hiding to achieve plausible deniability (i.e. so no one can prove any data ever existed).

Comment: @jw013 you are the first to mention encryption. Shredding data means it isn't recoverable. But my question is whether shredding has been testing against data recovery experts. Does it truly thwart recovery of the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a similar question to [How to wipe free disk space in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/19326/how-to-wipe-free-disk-space-in-linux/19377#19377)

Here is the answer I gave then;

> You can use a suite of tools called secure-delete.

`sudo apt-get install secure-delete`

This has four tools:

srm - securely delete an existing file
smem - securely delete traces of a file from ram
sfill - wipe all the space marked as empty on your hard drive
sswap - wipe all the data from you swap space.

From the man page of srm

> srm  is  designed to delete data on mediums in a secure manner which can not be recovered by thiefs, law enforce‐ment or other threats.  The wipe algorythm is based on the paper "Secure  Deletion  of  Data  from  Magnetic  and Solid-State  Memory" presented at the 6th Usenix Security Symposium by Peter Gutmann, one of the leading civilian cryptographers.
>
> The secure data deletion process of srm goes like this:
>
> - 1 pass with 0xff
> - 5 random passes. /dev/urandom is used for a secure RNG if available.
> - 27 passes with special values defined by Peter Gutmann.
> - 5 random passes. /dev/urandom is used for a secure RNG if available.
> - Rename the file to a random value
> - Truncate the file
>
> As an additional measure of security, the file is opened in O_SYNC mode and after each pass an  fsync()  call  is done.   srm writes 32k blocks for the purpose of speed, filling buffers of disk caches to force them to flush and overwriting old data which belonged to the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, @fnord_ix. Thank you very much for the citation. Googling Peter Gutmann turns up excellent details. He describes himself on his home page as a "Professional Paranoid." The Gutmann Method has a Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

shred can do multiple overwrites with its -iterations= parameter (25 by default) and that is the best way to make a file unrecoverable.

Comment: I'm looking for real world reports of shred working.