# Securely Delete unused disk space

Tags: windows, windows-xp, secure-erase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a program to truly delete all deleted files?](https://superuser.com/questions/33886/is-there-a-program-to-truly-delete-all-deleted-files)

I recently moved a bunch of files off my harddrive.  How can I zero out the unallocated disk space to make sure all the files I recently moved off the harddrive are unrecoverable?

This is windows-xp on my work computer, so I would prefer not to have to install anything if possible.  I am familiar with shred, but I think that only works if you still have the files.

Thanks

Comment: @kez: My question is a little different because I don't want to install anything, so the accepted answer on the other post doesn't work for me.  If you want to put your Cipher answer here, I would be glad to accept it.  (I read every post with "delete" in it before posting... but I missed that post because windows is one of my hidden tags... guess I'll have to learn from that).

Comment: If the answer on the dupe solves your problem, you can upvote that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install a 3rd-party app for this.

There are plenty - many are free.

In future you may want to use something like (true crypt dot org) to store sensitive files.

See http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-secure-erase-utility.htm

Also check out serase (I think that's what it's called), made by Mark Russinovich.  He has an awesome set of tools - search for sysinternals.  It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: CIPHER /W is a built-in command that will do the job :-)  http://superuser.com/questions/33886/is-there-a-program-to-truly-delete-all-deleted-files/175273#175273