# How to reset an NTFS MFT for no tracks of deleted files names to be found there?

Tags: hard-drive, security, data-recovery, wipe

When a file is deleted from the hard drive and the free space it used to occupy is securely overwritten (wiped), recovery tools can still usually find the file was there and show its name. As far as I understand this is because some data about old files is left in MFT area. How to eliminate this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a program to truly delete all deleted files?](http://superuser.com/questions/33886/is-there-a-program-to-truly-delete-all-deleted-files)

Comment: I've found CCleaner to offer "Wipe MFT Free Space" option, but haven't tested this yet... And I am pretty sceptical about it to help...

Comment: I believe that option will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This BCwipe worked for me, I mentioned it here:
https://superuser.com/a/1585146/470974

Answer (score 4):

The free software "PriVazer" has an option to securely delete file names on MFT and it doesn`t take that long! Another free prog. is "MooO Anti recovery". This also has an option to  securely erase old "deleted" file names.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Surely all you have to do is check out the free software I mentioned. Is that so difficult??

Comment: It is not that difficult to get this free software. "PriVazer" is an excellent programme!

Answer (score 3):

I've used the MFT wipe free space with CCleaner. (It does take forever, up to several days.)

Before running wipe, I could easily get a full list of previously deleted files with Recuva, despite the files being several years old and overwritten multiple times beyond recovery. This is because Recuva takes the list of files from MFT. https://www.piriform.com/docs/recuva/technical-information/how-recuva-works
(Unless you run the deepscan, which actually goes through the disk, seeing what's in there. This also takes forever, however.)

After running MFT wipe free space with CCleaner, Recuva finds nothing. Not without deepscan anyways. Therefore, I'm fairly certain CCleaner also takes MFT into account whilst wiping.

Answer (score 3):

First, check how many files Recuva reports that can be recovered. Say it is 1001.
Open a command window and create a temporary directory. Change to that directory.
**MKDIR C:\TempReco**
**CD C:\TempReco**
Create at least 1001 files in this directory using the command below with proper parameters.
**FOR /L %i in (1,1,1001) do echo willdelete>file%i.tmp**
When this completes, delete the files with either from command window or by locating with Windows Explorer. Then, empty the Recycle Bin.
When you check again with Recuva, it will only show filenames you have just deleted.

Comment: In case Windows does not clean unused space when storing a new name in an MFT record, you may want to use a longer name in the 'file%i.tmp' template, like 'atleastfirst80charactersofdeletednamesshouldbecleared%i.tmp'.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the program PrivaZer for several years now, and it's a great program for completely cleaning and deleting unwanted files from the hard drive - including the MFT entries.  It deletes all the temp. files, cleans the disk fragments and deletes any cookies.  Great program!

Comment: PrivaZer all the way! Easy and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The Most Reliable way to do this is also the simplest

1. copy your files to a second hard drive
2. wipe the source drive using something like DBAN and reformat
3. transfer the data back.

This has to be done with a file level copy utility like robocopy since using imaging software will copy the entire partition MFT and all.

Of course this is only practical for non system disks while it is theoretically possible to do this with a OS drive you need to ensure that your using a tool capable of copying hidden and system files along with the ACL's. You will also need to perform additional steps in the recovery console to rebuild the boot sector, MBR and BCD from scratch to ensure that the system will see the new partition as bootable. Its mostly a crap shoot and you would be better off just doing a clean reinstall of your OS

Comment: might wanna use something like winrar in Store mode to backup to a single file, that way when you delete backup you won't have inflated MFT.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, it is not possible.

The MFT is a complex dynamic table file at the heart of the NTFS. 
To change one small part of it, corrupts the whole drive.

MS isn't telling how it is structured, and no one is going to 
risk putting out a application on a trial and error basis, that 'cleans' the file names, 
if there is any chance it will destroy the system.

(Oh yes, insert negative comments about MS exposing peoples data here.)

So depending on the pros and cons, you may want to restart with a fresh install, and then use less sensitive file names and use secure deletion at the recycling bin.
Use TrueCrypt containers to keep files separate from programs.
Perhaps FDE (Full Disk Encryption) is a option if it is that important.

To make things clear to others, it is not what Ccleaner and the others do, 
drive wiping the MTF and defragging it and all the rest doesn't clean the MFT names.
They overwrite the file spaces in the MTF, but the names remain. 
It is the deletion of the FILE NAMES ONLY that the OP is asking about.
(File names that can only be seen with specialized file recovery applications)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Paragon Hard Disk Manager Suite (Pro?)](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-professional/features.html) can help you do this [by shrinking the MFT](http://kb.paragon-software.com/paragon/include/templ/object2.jsp?catId=2124&objId=6218&statId=1813399&foLang=en):

> As the `$MFT` grows, it will occupy the increasing amount of space in the MFT Zone, and the current size of `$MFT` is totally unrelated to the size of the MFT Zone.
>   When one executes the "Compact MFT" (also may be called “Shrink MFT” in some editions) operation, the `$MFT` itself will be shrinked, but the MFT Zone will remain intact - just a block of reserved free space.

It can shrink the MFT, which means deleted file records won't be there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Revo Uninstaller freeware wipes the MFT almost completely. Tested on formated WD 500GB with AVG PC tuneup utility to view the MFT size before Revo Unistaller and after Revo Unistaller. MFT almost completely gone while before it was enormous.

http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

Go to Tools --> Tracks Cleaner --> Evidence Remover --> select drive and run it.

Answer (score -1):

This Windows built-in does it nicely, though takes a while.  Both MFT and drivespace on C:

```
    CIPHER /W:C:
```

> /W        Removes data from available unused disk space on the entire
> volume. If this option is chosen, all other options are ignored.
> The directory specified can be anywhere in a local volume. If it
> is a mount point or points to a directory in another volume, the
> data on that volume will be removed.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, we prefer complete answers here.  I have edited it to show you what could have been done here.  This gives the readers some confidence that this is a valid answer.  Please keep this in mind.

Comment: I think it does not touch the MFT, [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/use-cipher-to-overwrite-deleted-data) .. "The cipher /w command does not work for files that are smaller than 1 KB" .. This refers to resident files and suggests MFT entries are not overwritten.

Comment: Not all files that are smaller than 1KB are resident in the MFT record. First, the MFT record size is not necessarily 1KB (it can be larger when the NTFS volume was prepared); then the MFT record starts at least by a "basic attributes" entry which consumes some bytes and which is always resident; it may be then followed by a resident entry for MFT extension (if there are too many attributes than can fit the MFT record itself, e.g. for security attributes). Small files (or ADS) will be resident only if there remains some space. NTFS has priorities for which attributes will be resident.