# Need Program to delete old file path information for deleted files

Tags: path

Is there a program that will delete old file path information for deleted files?  After running CCleaner to wipe free space on a drive, when I then run Recuva to scan for deleted files on a drive, all of the old file path information is still shown for the deleted files on the drive in question which were overwritten by CCleaner. This concerns both Windows 7 & Windows 10 PC's.

Answer (score -1):

CCLeaner probably isn't wiping the MFT free space as well as the actual free space on this disk.  Later versions of CCLeaner should be able to wipe both.  The MFT is probably where recuva is getting the file information from.

From CCleaner's website
https://www.ccleaner.com/docs/ccleaner/ccleaner-settings/changing-ccleaner-settings
"To set CCleaner to clean MFT free space (NTFS drives only):

The Master File Table (MFT) contains an index of the files on an NTFS drive. As the computer overwrites and deletes files, the MFT can accumulate free space which may contain remnants of index pointers to deleted files. You can now set CCleaner to wipe the MFT free space, just as you have been able to set it to wipe free drive space.

To enable MFT free space cleaning, select the Wipe MFT Free Space check box.

Note: If you select both Wipe Free Space and Wipe MFT Free Space, CCleaner will wipe the MFT free space first."

Comment: Patrick - Thanks so much!!    Zack

Comment: Hopefully thats helpful.  

why the down vote though?

Comment: I can't find "Wipe MFT Free Space" option anymore in free CCleaner.

Comment: This worked for me: https://superuser.com/a/1585146/470974