# Wipe unallocated disk space in Windows and clean or rename file in directory structures

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, secure-erase

I want a way to clean free space in Windows once I delete the data, so that:

- The files are no longer recoverable by any disk recovery tools
- The file names are no longer visible in any disk recovery tools

For the purpose of this task, I have tried using Cipher /w after deleting all the required file. But when I opened disk drill (recovery tool), it was able to see the file names in the underlying disk. Although they were no longer recoverable, I still want to make sure that they are not visible in the disk.

I also tried SDelete to no avail. I was still able to see the underlying file names and folder structures.

**Note: I did not delete files or folders using SDelete**, I only used it for cleaning the empty disk space later.

I saw a few threads with respect to this discussion, but none of them provided a direct answer. It would be great if someone can help.

Comment: `cipher.exe` does not remove file info (name, size, folder structure etc) from the Master File Table, but it does erase the actual file's data. You want a different kind of "erase" tool that checks the MFT (though these are often very slow): https://superuser.com/questions/816152/deleting-file-names-from-mft

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting file names from MFT](https://superuser.com/questions/816152/deleting-file-names-from-mft)

Comment: I have used Eraser which has both those features.

Comment: You could simply reformat the disk, and this will reinitialize the file-table.

Comment: @harrymc I want to preserve other data on the disk. It is to selectively delete stuff on drive and make sure no traces remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to clean out the deleted file names from the MFT, for which
you need a third-party tool.

One such tool is the free
[Prevent Recovery](https://www.cyrobo.com/software/systm-en-allabout-prerec-.php).
With it you can either erase the free space or the deleted
file-entries in the MFT, or both.

You may find a description of the tool in the article
[Prevent Recovery Overwrites Free Space on Hard Drives](https://www.trishtech.com/2019/04/prevent-recovery-overwrites-free-space-on-hard-drives/).

Note that for a large disk this operation may take a long time.

Here is the most relevant screenshot :

[image]

---

Another tool that can clean the MFT and the disk is
[CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/).

See the description in the article
[How to Clean MFT (Master File Table) on NTFS Drives](https://www.trishtech.com/2020/01/how-to-clean-mft-master-file-table-on-ntfs-drives/).